# VB.Net Regex...extracting a value

Tags: regex, vb.net

How in VB.Net can I extract the value from a string using the RegularExpressions class?  For example, say I have the string:

```
[Mon Jan 4 2011] Blah Blah2 Other text
```

and I want to return the "Mon Jan 4 2011" portion in to a variable.  I thought you would use the "Regex.Replace" method but I can't seem to figure out how to extract the portion of the string I want.

Answer (score 5):

In this case, I don't think you need to replace the text, you need to match the text instead.

```
Regex.Match(input, "(?<=\[)[^\]]+").Value
```

This takes all the text from right after the first `[` up until the next `]`.
Edit: missed a square bracket.

Comment: Returns an error when run:

    parsing "(?<=\[)[^\]+" - Unterminated [] set.

Comment: I fixed it... must have just missed you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use match groups - specifically name the part of the expression you want and reference it by name:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Module Example
   Public Sub Main()
      Dim pattern As String = "\[(?<datestring>[^\]]+)\]"
      Dim input As String = "[Mon Jan 4 2011] Blah Blah2 Other text"
      Dim match As Match = Regex.Match(input, pattern)

      ' Get the first named group.
      Dim group1 As Group = match.Groups.Item("datestring")
      Console.WriteLine("Group 'datestring' value: {0}", If(group1.Success, group1.Value, "Empty"))
   End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: Close, but this returns the leading square bracket along with the date string.

Comment: See my revision - should work now.  Get a handle on match/matches and groups and you'll want to use regular expressions for everything.

Answer (score 0):

Try with regex:

```
\x5B([^\x5D]+)
```

Comment: This also returns the leading left square bracket along with the contents between the square brackets....close but not quite.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use this code to achieve your goal:

```
    Dim str As String = "[Mon Jan 4 2011] Blah Blah2 Other text"
    Dim m As Match = Regex.Match(str, "\[(?<tag>[^]]*)")
    If (m.Success) Then
        Debug.Print(m.Result("${tag}"))   ' Check "Output Window"
    End If
```

In this code matched result will be stored in named group `tag` and will be used accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

i'm suggesting you to follow the article here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9099/The-30-Minute-Regex-Tutorial

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.