# Value of Type Match Cannot Be Converted To String

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net

I'm currently trying to loop over a folder of text files and read them. After I've read them, I'd like to extract a certain portion of the name of the files using Regular Expressions, however I am getting the error `Value of Type Match Cannot Be Converted To String`.

I have tried using `Cstr` however this doesn't seem to solve my problem.

Code I am using:

```
 Dim fileentries As String() = Directory.GetFiles("D:\User\BackUp\Project\bin\Debug\Orders")
 For Each entry In fileentries
        Dim match As New List(Of String)
        Dim regexmatch As Match = Regex.Match(entry, "Order_\d\d-\d\d-[\d]{4}_[\d]{6}")
        match.Add(CStr(regexmatch))

    Next
```

Here the Regular Expressions section is working, it seems to extract the correct portion of the filename I want however specifically with line `match.Add(Cstr(regexmatch))` I am getting the error I've described.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Because `Match` isn't a `String`... `Regex.Match` returns an object that contains information about the match (you need the `Value` property), please [**read more here**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.match?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Comment: Look through any of these answers, possible duplicate of [VB.Net Regex...extracting a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6431799/vb-net-regex-extracting-a-value)

Comment: I should have remembered to look there first, should have just pressed F1. I will remember this for future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access the `.Value` property of the `Match` object, but it is recommended to check if there is a match at all:

```
Dim regexmatch As Match = Regex.Match(entry, "Order_\d\d-\d\d-\d{4}_\d{6}")
If regexmatch.Success Then
    match.Add(regexmatch.Value)
End If
```

See the [VB.NET demo](https://ideone.com/PfYFVf):

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
' ... 
Dim match As New List(Of String)()
Dim entry As String = "XXXX_Order_12-12-1234_123456_irrelevant.txt"
Dim regexmatch As Match = Regex.Match(entry, "Order_\d\d-\d\d-\d{4}_\d{6}")
If regexmatch.Success Then
    match.Add(regexmatch.Value)
End If
Console.WriteLine(match(0)) ' => Order_12-12-1234_123456
```

Note that `[\d]{4}` is equal to `\d{4}`, no need to put a single atom into a character class.

Comment: Thank you, I realise this was really simple, like just adding `.Value` however it's now cleared things up and the loop works correctly.